# How to ensure the uniqueness of a column when updating a record in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails app I am generating tokens with this method inside my `User` model:

```
def generate_token(column)
  update_column(column, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64)
end
```

I know this is extremely unlikely to ever happen but how can I ensure that no two tokens are ever created with the same value?

Comment: Any special reason for using `update_column` rather than `update_attribute` ?

Comment: No, not really. Isn't the first one preferred in Rails 4? I think I read something... But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think they are both available for a reason. One of them skips validations, so you can't use `validates_uniqueness_of` ... Depends on your usage of `generate_token`

Comment: `update_attribute` is deprecated now in favor of `update_column`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean you want to ensure that the token is unique?

Add an instance method to do this:

```
def generate_token
  begin
    self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(token: token)
end
```

For the sake of completeness, and as others have pointed out, this will not **absolutely** guarantee uniqueness. The only sure way is to add a unique constraint at the database level:

```
add_index :people, :token, unique: true
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! But this doesn't actually *save* the token, right?

Comment: Don't forget to add an index on `token` on your `user` table.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a database constraint too to be sure :

```
add_index :people, :token, :unique => true
```